# Could not find Docker hostname on Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, elixir, phoenix-framework, gitlab-ci, ecto

I have an app inside a Docker container based on Elixir image, that need to connect to a database and run tests using a Gitlab runner.

The build stage works fine but there is a problem to connect to a database to run tests. I tried both connecting to a service and running another database container, but from the logs it looks like the problem is with the Phoenix app:

```
** (RuntimeError) :database is nil in repository configuration
    lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:121: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.storage_up/1
    lib/mix/tasks/ecto.create.ex:40: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Create.run/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:675: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:675: Enum.each/2
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:301: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:75: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

This is how the `config/test.exs` file looks like

```
config :app, App.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: System.get_env("POSTGRES_USER"),
  password: System.get_env("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
  database: System.get_env("POSTGRES_DB"),
  hostname: System.get_env("POSTGRES_HOSTNAME"),
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox
```

This is the output from the runner:

```
$ docker run --rm -t $CONTAINER echo $MIX_ENV $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_HOSTNAME $POSTGRES_DB
test username db test_db
```

<s>I'm trying to figure out why I get this error `:database is nil`, and if it is related to Gitlab, Ecto or Phoenix.</s>

#### Edit

I wrote static values in the `config/*.exs` files (for some reason it didn't pick them up), but now it can't find the postgresql hostname. Although the postgresql instance is running it can't find it.

I checked if the instance is running with `docker ps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the message `:database is nil in repository configuration` it seems to me like your `POSTGRES_DB` variable is not set. You can try to change that configuration line to

```
database: System.get_env("POSTGRES_DB") || "postgres"
```

to see whether you still get the same error. If you don't, you can debug from there.

Comment: It didn't work with a static name and the environment variable is set when I run `docker run ... echo $POSTGRES_DB`. It need to be set for the database as well.